# Want to add logo image and add some UI in RSViewerPage.aspx page under "/_layouts/15/ReportServer/"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, application-pages, layouts

I want to add one image as a logo in "RSViewerPage.aspx" in sharepoint 2013 site under "/_layouts/15" folder. Where SSRS reports are shown. I want to add some UI to that page, as per my requirement. When I saw that page, "RSViewerPage.aspx" is not refering any master page. And that when I did changes on that page they are not getting reflected on that page means on our reports. Why does that happen so?
Even I made a copy of that folder, "LAYOUTS" folder and did changes there.
Making changes in original "RSViewerPage.aspx" as told above is also not making any difference what should I do? Any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer the thing was that, I need to make changes in the "Web Front End Server" parallel to my WFE server. When I did the same changes there everything got right, the changes were reflected. And the page stopped giving me the correlation ID error. Now whenever, I hit the URL of the new layouts folder. It shows me the customized "RSViewerPage.aspx".